# Complex matrix factorization into three

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, matrix-decomposition, sparse-matrices

If you have complex matrix M, how can you decompose M into three matrices, A, B, C? They are all complex and n by n matrices.

Additional information of matrices A, B, C is as follows. 
A and C are symmetric (possibly hermitian), unitary 
B has only diagonal components (or mainly close-diagonal components).

Obviously, this is an underdetermined problem. I thought this is intractable. But, I just wondered if there exist any ways to tackle this problem (or some approximation/relaxation) I'd appreciate your help!

Comment: Have you heard about the [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition)? It's relatively close to what you want, although $A$ and $C$ aren't necessarily symmetric / Hermitian.

Comment: Oh, yea I knew it's close to SVD. What I really want to obtain is correct matrix B, whose elements are complex numbers.. So, I thought I might need to do some optimization. no ideas on how to start though...